# I cannot implement Knight and Knave problem in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have recently read a document about Prolog and I am new to this language please help me.
In the document as I've read it says this code:

```
solve(Clues, Solution) :-
    Solution = [isa(a,A), isa(b,B)],
    Types = [knights, soldiers], 
    member(A, Types),
    member(B, Types),
    consequences(Solution, Statements, Consequences),
    consistent(Solution, Consequences).
```

But I don't know how to implement these following questions,

You meet two inhabitants, A and B.

### A says: "Either I am a knave or B is a knight."

### A says: "I am a knave, but B isn't."

### A says: "At least one of us is a knave."

Comment: what text did you get the code from?

Comment: There are two singleton variable errors in this block of code, so I think if you want help, you should either ask your professor or post the document.